# pandas vectorized lookup without deprecated lookup()

Tags: python, pandas

My problem concerns `lookup()`, which is to be deprecated. So I'm looking for an alternative. Documentation suggests using `loc()` (which does not seem to work with a vectorized approach) or `melt()` (which seems quite convoluted). Furthermore, the documentation suggests `factorize()` which (I think) does not work for my setup.

Here is the problem:
I have a 2-column DataFrame with x,y-values.

```
k = 20
y = random.choices(range(1,4),k=k)
x = random.choices(range(1,7),k=k)
tuples = list(zip(x,y))
df = pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=["x", "y"])
df
```

And I have several DataFrames in crosstab-format of `df`. For example one called `Cij`:

```
Concordance table (Cij):
x     1     2     3    4     5     6  RTotal
y                                           
1   16     15    13  NaN     5   NaN     108
2   NaN    12   NaN   15   NaN   NaN      87
3   NaN   NaN     6  NaN    13    14     121
```

I now want to perform a vectorized lookup in `Cij` from xy-pairs in `df` to generate a new column `CrC` in `df`. Which so far looked like this (plain and simple):

```
df["Crc"] = Cij.lookup(df["y"],df["x"])
```

How can I achieve the same thing without `lookup()`? Or did I just not understand the suggested alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

**Addendum**: Working code example as requested.

```
data = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,3],[1,3],[1,5],[2,2],[2,4],[2,4],[2,4],[2,4],[2,4],[3,3],[3,3],[3,5],[3,5],[3,5],[3,6],[3,6],[3,6],[3,6],[3,6]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["y", "x"])

# crosstab of df
ct_a = pd.crosstab(df["y"], df["x"])
Cij = pd.DataFrame([], index=ct_a.index, columns=ct_a.columns) #one of several dfs in ct_a layout

#row-wise, than column-wise filling of Cij
for i in range(ct_a.shape[0]):           
  for j in range(ct_a.shape[1]):
    if ct_a.iloc[i,j] != 0:
      Cij.iloc[i,j]= ct_a.iloc[i+1:,j+1:].sum().sum()+ct_a.iloc[:i,:j].sum().sum()

#vectorized lookup, to be substituted with future-proof method
df["Crc"] = Cij.lookup(df["y"],df["x"])
```

Note: In this case loop-based "filling" of `Cij` is fine, since crosstabs of `df` are always small. However, `df` itself can be very large so vectorized lookup is a necessity.

Comment: can you provide a full reproducible example with the output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added a full reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can `stack` Cij and then `reindex` based on a list of tuples created by using `zip`:

```
df['Crc'] = Cij.stack().reindex(zip(df['y'], df['x'])).to_numpy()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    y  x   Crc
0   1  1  16.0
1   1  1  16.0
2   1  2  15.0
3   1  2  15.0
4   1  2  15.0
5   1  3  13.0
6   1  3  13.0
7   1  5   5.0
8   2  2    12
9   2  4    15
10  2  4    15
11  2  4    15
12  2  4    15
13  2  4    15
14  3  3   6.0
15  3  3   6.0
16  3  5  13.0
17  3  5  13.0
18  3  5  13.0
19  3  6  14.0
20  3  6  14.0
21  3  6  14.0
22  3  6  14.0
23  3  6  14.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Still slower (2secs, instead of 300ms) but other from that, it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#looking-up-values-by-index-column-labels) path in the docs, you can replicate the lookup functionality:

```py
x_index, x_uniques = pd.factorize(df.x)

arrays = (Cij
          .reindex(columns = x_uniques)
          .to_numpy()[df.y.factorize()[0], x_index]
         )

df['r'] = arrays

df
    y  x     r   Crc
0   1  1  16.0  16.0
1   1  1  16.0  16.0
2   1  2  15.0  15.0
3   1  2  15.0  15.0
4   1  2  15.0  15.0
5   1  3  13.0  13.0
6   1  3  13.0  13.0
7   1  5   5.0   5.0
8   2  2    12  12.0
9   2  4    15  15.0
10  2  4    15  15.0
11  2  4    15  15.0
12  2  4    15  15.0
13  2  4    15  15.0
14  3  3   6.0   6.0
15  3  3   6.0   6.0
16  3  5  13.0  13.0
17  3  5  13.0  13.0
18  3  5  13.0  13.0
19  3  6  14.0  14.0
20  3  6  14.0  14.0
21  3  6  14.0  14.0
22  3  6  14.0  14.0
23  3  6  14.0  14.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked `df["Crc"] = Cij.loc[df["y"], df["x"]]`, you will notice that it returns an array.  By comparing this with `df["Crc"] = Cij.lookup(df["y"],df["x"])`, you will also notice that the leading diagonal is the same (which makes sense).  Therefore, you can add `np.diagonal` to return what you need:

```
df["Crc"] = np.diagonal(Cij.loc[df["y"], df["x"]])
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work. And I did not notice that. :) However, once `df` gets larger it takes much longer (~tenfold for 10k xy-pairs) and crashes my runtime due to RAM limitations at 100k xy-pairs. With `lookup()` my whole codes takes ~300ms for 250k xy-pairs and I'd like to end up in the vincinity of that with the `lookup()`-substitue.